# How to add a local date variable without time in stack workflow

Tags: slack

I'm trying to create a new workflow which posts a message with the local current date.
But I'm only able to create a message with todays date and time. Want to know how can I create a variable with both local and UTC date with/without time and different time formats.

Attached Screenshot

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

What I've been doing is keeping a separate "Date Time" sheet with =now() functions. So like this:

```
Date/Time   Value
Date        =now() (Format the date to display however you like.)
Time        =now() (Format the time to display however you like.)
```

Then follow with two different Select a Spreadsheet Row steps for the date and time, selecting the row name to get the values. Then when you go to send out a message, you can select the two Value item variables to put out the date and time, which will correspond with your spreadsheet time. If you need to alter the time at all, you can subtract or add the amount of hours you need to the =now() function.

Of course, you can just do one or the other or both. They'll go in as separate variables.